# Different Slide Panels in different sections of the same page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn jquery, so please forgive my lack of knowledge. Ok, what I trying to achieve is a page with several sections. Each section will be 100vh and will have a background image and a button. The Button is supposed to slide a panel from left. I found a code which works perfectly. The problem starts when I try to repeat the same on another section of the same page. Then only the 1st slide will work and no other.

I tried to give different names in the divs and even different classes with no luck. Anyone who could help with this?
Thank you in advance!

Here is the original code

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 //open the lateral panel
 $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible');
 });
 //clode the lateral panel
 $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
    if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-
close') ) { 
        $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
});
```

and here is the HTML

```
<main class="cd-main-content">
    <h1>Slide In Panel</h1>
    <a href="#0" class="cd-btn">Fire Panel</a>
    <!-- your content here -->
</main>

  <div class="cd-panel1 from-left is-visible">
    <header class="cd-panel-header">
        <h1>Title Goes Here</h1>
        <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>
    </header>

    <div class="cd-panel-container">
        <div class="cd-panel-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. /p>

        </div> <!-- cd-panel-content -->
    </div> <!-- cd-panel-container -->
```

CSS for is visible

```
 .is-visible .cd-panel-container {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
 }

.cd-panel.is-visible {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
-moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
transition: visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible::after {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
-webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
-moz-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
transition: background 0.3s 0s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::before {
-webkit-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
-moz-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
}


 .cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  }
```

Comment: Where do you define the class `is-visible` ?

Comment: I just edited the HTML code with the is visible. thank you @SamuelAsor

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean the CSS declaration of the class `is-visible`.

Comment: @SamuelAsor I added the CSS that are meant for the is-visible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete. But here's some explanation to get the result you're looking for.

First, in order to have that in different places, you need to have another button that will trigger the display of the panel. You can call the first button `.btn1` and the second `.btn2`, give the panels a different class too.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpn0jg2L/), it should give you some light.

Comment: Thank you so much @Samuel Asor. I have tried to give different classes, names but always only the 1st-panel slides. So, I will try to find what is missing from the code and I will be back, maybe with a complete code. Thank you!